# eclipse plug-in extension point for CompletionProposal inserted/used

Tags: java, eclipse, autocomplete, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-wtp

I have extended my eclipse xml-auto-completion proposals as shown in this [tutorial](http://kofler.nonblocking.at/2013/07/extending-the-content-assist-capabilities-of-the-eclipse-xml-editor/).

Further on, I'd like to manipulate the underlying xml-document (e.g. add additional sub-elements to the selected node) **when** one of my suplied **proposals is inserted**, but I can't find any extension point matching.

Is there a solution within the `org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist` package that I'm missing or can someone give me a hint which extension point would be useful ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write your own implementation of `ICompletionProposal` rather than using the provided `CompletionProposal` class (which is `final` so it can't be extended).

The `void apply(IDocument document)` method is called to apply the completion proposal to the current document - you should be able to do what you want in this method.